# HUD is missing in Battlefield 3?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

I seriously don't know what key I hit, but it turned off the hub for the gun in BF3. The hub located in the lower right corner is now gone, and I have no idea how to bring it back. I've pressed every key on the keyboard without luck.

[image]

Comment: Oh noes Karkand... didn't you already spend enough time on it in BF2?? :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is that you've joined a hardcore server.  The hardcore rule-set makes it so you can't see your ammo or your health.

http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Hardcore

If this isn't the problem then it is unlikely that you've hit a button by accident as this isn't a feature you can simply toggle on and off with a hotkey, it is likely a corrupted installation that can be fixed by reinstalling the game or perhaps your GPU drivers.

Comment: I thought you have no minimap when playing hardcore? At least this was true for BC2.

Comment: thanks, I must have joined a few hc games in a row. The hub returned later when I changed servers.

Comment: @Streuner There are a few differences between BC2 and BF3's HC modes, check out the wiki link and it lists the differences.

Comment: Hardcore mode has a minimap by default in BF3. They added the feature recently (within the last few months) that gives server admins the option to disabled the minimap in HC mode.