# Health and ammo not displaying in Battlefield 4

Tags: battlefield-4

I used to play Battlefield 4 on the PS3 and just recently moved to PC.

Health and Ammo HUD section is not being displayed. I also seem to have the same problem with the orange spotting triangle above an enemy's head.

Does someone know how to display Health and Ammo HUD section? Is there an option that must be activated?

Comment: @Galabyca Please stop adding bold to suggested edits.  It does not help.

Comment: @Frank, This is not  an edit  for embolding. I edited the whole question and all sentences for a better fit with the Arqade's scope. I took time to add bold to the main question as an addition to this edit. Thank you for the advise. However, I don't think I'm wrong. If you don't agree we can discuss this in private :)

Comment: @Galabyca I'm not criticizing the rest of the edit.  This is specifically bolding questions.  You already made a meta about it.  Don't do it, was the result.  It does not help.  It, in fact, makes it worse.

Comment: @Frank, the first edit was accepted by Dragonrage and Timelord64. Now, if you think "It does not help. It, in fact, makes it worse.", it's alright, but I think there is no objective answer, as the way we can interpret the answer on the meta post.

Comment: @Galabyca That's not what that meta post says.  You can interpret it that way if you want, but I'm telling you right now, that's wrong.  Either way, though, I'm just trying to point you in the right direction.  I'll be reverting those edits as I see them.

Comment: @Frank, As long as we can work together on the questions themselves and improve Arqade, there is no problem in reverting edits for my bold characters. =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40811/discussion-between-galabyca-and-frank).

Comment: Possibly related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114304/hud-is-missing-in-battlefield-3

Answer (score 3):

Graphics options - HUD opacity

Or you're in hardcore mode